# Adding colnames to a dataframe

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

When I read the csv it adds a X to my first element. I don't know what's wrong?

Also when I add colnames to a dataframe my first row disappears.

```
> grocery<-read.csv("groceries.csv")
> grocery
       spinach X2.00
1         rice   3.0
2 toilet paper   4.0
3        bread   2.4
4         milk   3.1
5        apple   0.4
> 
> class(grocery)
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(grocery)<-c("item","price")
> grocery
          item price
1         rice   3.0
2 toilet paper   4.0
3        bread   2.4
4         milk   3.1
5        apple   0.4
>
```

Here's the raw csv:

```
spinach,2.00
rice,3.00
toilet paper,4.00
bread,2.40
milk,3.10
apple,0.40
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
read.csv("groceries.csv", header=F)
```

by default that function assumes the first row of your data is a header, and uses it for colnames instead of as data.  Since numbers are not valid colnames, it prepends `X` to the numbers to make it character.  When you re-set colnames, you overwrite what used to be the first row of your data that was actually saved as colnames instead of as a row of data.

Setting `header=F` will prevent `read.csv` from using the first row as colnames.

Answer (score 1):

you're also losing your first row of data, spinach and 2.00. It's making those the column names, 2.00 becomes X2.00 to comply with R naming conventions of permissible names. Add column headers